# Apply C# syntax highlighting to the ravendb tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

I would like to request that any question tagged with [ravendb](/questions/tagged/ravendb) have C# syntax highlighting applied even if the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag is not present.

95% of the questions have their code examples in C#, and RavenDB uses C# flavored linq for its indexes - so it's almost always applicable.

I am aware of how to apply syntax highlighting manually with the `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` tagging, but it always seems silly to edit a question just for that alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've turned on automatic syntax highlighting for [ravendb](/questions/tagged/ravendb) - this will attempt to auto-detect the language in use, which should suffice for C# code without precluding the use of other languages.

Comment: Thanks you! The only other syntax that comes into play sometimes is json (raw json, not javascript).  Will that be detected as well?

Comment: Should be - let me know if it isn't.