# Are we forced to use [C++] tag when asking Qt questions to get code highlight?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, syntax-highlighting

I used to include [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag in my questions about Qt. But after [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19523375/2) I didn't include it anymore.

I am not Qt developer - that's what I don't ask very much Qt questions.

But I am suspicious that we need [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag when asking Qt questions for code highlight.

Randomly I will take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18927534/1420197) (I added the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18927534/4)) as an example:

> [image]
>
> It doesn't contain [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag

So, what alternatives do we have for syntax-highlight when not using [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag but using [qt](/questions/tagged/qt)?

---

Update: Even we can set highlighting using `language ...` it would be better to add highlighting for [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) tag. Turning my question in a feature request.

Comment: Might be worth adding the C++ language hint to the qt tag if they tend to be considered seperate languages (but with highly similar syntax)

Comment: The developers can turn on syntax highlighting for this tag, as shown [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161726/apply-c-syntax-highlighting-to-the-ravendb-tag), so you could change this question to a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: Not a dupe, @Stijn has the right answer.

Comment: Note that the tag is also used on Python questions, where defaulting to c++ highlighting would no doubt annoy people.

Comment: @Wooble FWIW, the Python tag *does* have it's highlighting set to `lang-py`, so since it's a far more used tag, its own highlighting would still override the Qt tag setting.

Comment: @animuson: sure, but if C++ people using [qt] don't need to tag [c++], why should Python people use a [python] tag with the [qt] tag? (I guess the broader question is why you wouldn't want to use a language tag all the time if you're asking about a specific language).

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you can always do this:

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->

    #include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
    #include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
    #include <QQmlContext>
```

Comment: Note there are other tags with this issue eg c++-amp

Comment: I transformed my question in a feature request.